# Dealing with floats in my website

Tags: html, css, web

I am working on my first website using html and css. For the portfolio area/ work area I would like to have three images and three descriptions next to them but i want to alternate them. For example, my row one will have an image on the left and text on the right. My row two will have text on the left and image on the right and my row three will be the same as my row one. I dont know the best way to go about doing this at all, can anyone help me achieve this layout because I just feel like im adding more and more unnecessary code since I dont know what im doing.

HTML:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="author" content="David Espejo">
    <meta name="description" content="Providing small businesses and individuals websites using wordpress">
    <meta name="keywords" content="web,design,wordpress,HTML,CSS,PHP">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> <!-- for mobile devices -->
    <title>DEdesigns</title>
    <script src="html5shiv.js"></script>    <!-- allows html 5 styling -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css"> <!-- a modern CSS reset -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <header id="main-header">
        <h1>DEdesigns</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header> <!-- end #main-header -->
    <article id="about-me">
        <h1>About Me</h1>
            <figure>
                <img src="http://people.mozilla.com/~faaborg/files/shiretoko/firefoxIcon/firefox-128-noshadow.png" width="" height="">
                <figcaption>An image of myself</figcaption>
            </figure>
            <p>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
                Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a
                galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but
                also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged
            </p>
            <input type="submit" value="Call Me">
    </article> <!-- end #about-me -->
    <article id="gallery">
        <h1>My Work</h1>
        <div id="gallery-container">
            <div class="row-one clear-fix">
                <figure>
                    <img src="http://people.mozilla.com/~faaborg/files/shiretoko/firefoxIcon/firefox-128-noshadow.png" width="#" height="#">
                    <figcaption>SalonSociel website</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <p>
                    A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website.
                    A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website.
                </p>
            </div>
            <!--  ends first row -->
            <div class="row-two clear-fix">
                <p>
                    A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website.
                </p>
                 <figure>
                    <img src="http://people.mozilla.com/~faaborg/files/shiretoko/firefoxIcon/firefox-128-noshadow.png" width="#" height="#">
                    <figcaption>JJ and Sons Electric website</figcaption>
                </figure>
            </div>
            <!-- ends second row -->
            <div class="row-three clear-fix">
                <figure>
                    <img src="http://people.mozilla.com/~faaborg/files/shiretoko/firefoxIcon/firefox-128-noshadow.png" width="#" height="#">
                    <figcaption>Thetwoedgesword website</figcaption>
                </figure>
                <p>
                    A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website.
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- ends third row -->
        </div> <!-- ends #gallery-container -->
    </article> <!-- end #gallery -->
    <article id="services">
        <h1>Services</h1>
         <ol>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
        </ol>
    </article> <!-- end #services -->
    <article id="contact-me">
        <h1>Contact Me</h1>
        <p>some contact me stuff goes here</p>
    </article> <!-- end #contact-me -->
    <footer>
        <p>This is my fotter</p>
    </footer>    
</div> <!-- end #container -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
   #container {
    width: 100%;
    background: #4de8d0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font: 1em/2 sans-serif;
    margin-top: 50px;
}


#main-header {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

#main-header h1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 30px;
}

nav ul {
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}

nav, nav li {
    display: inline-block;
}

nav {
    display: table;
    background: #c3c3c3;
    height: 50px;
}

nav a {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 0px 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}

h1, h2 { text-align: center; }



#about-me {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #32c6cd;
    color: white;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
    text-align: center;
}

#about-me figure {
    text-align: center;
}

#about-me p {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 0 5%;
}

#gallery-container {
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #c3c3c3;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

#gallery-container figure {
    width: 25%;
    text-align: center;
}

#gallery-container p {

}


.row-one, .row-two, .row-three {
    border: 1px solid green;
    background: lightblue;
}



.clear-fix {
    overflow: auto;
    zoom: 1;
}

.row-one figure {
    float: left;
    background: blue;
}

.row-one p {

}

.row-two figure {
    float: right;
    background: blue;
}

.row-one p {
    background: red;
    padding: 3%;
}

.row-two figure {
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
    background: red;
}

.row-two p {
    background: red;
    padding: 3%;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what kishanW said. You can use the nth-child pseudo selector depending on your browser support:

Here's a working example with your HTML, I just added a row class and removed row-one, etc...

```css
.clear-fix {
  overflow: auto;
  zoom: 1;
}
#gallery-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #c3c3c3;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#gallery-container .row {
  padding: 2.5%;
}
#gallery-container .row figure {
  background: #00F;
  width: 25%;
  text-align: center;
}
#gallery-container .row p {
  background: #F00;
  width: 67.5%;
  padding: 2.5%;
  margin: 0;
}
#gallery-container .row:nth-child(odd) figure {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2.5% 0 0;
}
#gallery-container .row:nth-child(odd) p {
  float: left;
}
#gallery-container .row:nth-child(even) figure {
  float: right;
  margin: 0 0 0 2.5%;
}
#gallery-container .row:nth-child(even) p {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="gallery-container">
  <div class="row clear-fix">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://people.mozilla.com/~faaborg/files/shiretoko/firefoxIcon/firefox-128-noshadow.png" width="#" height="#">
      <figcaption>SalonSociel website</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p>
      A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website.
    </p>
  </div>
  <!--  ends first row -->
  <div class="row clear-fix">
    <p>
      A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website.
    </p>
    <figure>
      <img src="http://people.mozilla.com/~faaborg/files/shiretoko/firefoxIcon/firefox-128-noshadow.png" width="#" height="#">
      <figcaption>JJ and Sons Electric website</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </div>
  <!-- ends second row -->
  <div class="row clear-fix">
    <figure>
      <img src="http://people.mozilla.com/~faaborg/files/shiretoko/firefoxIcon/firefox-128-noshadow.png" width="#" height="#">
      <figcaption>Thetwoedgesword website</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p>
      A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website. A descripton of the website.
    </p>
  </div>
  <!-- ends third row -->
</div>
<!-- ends #gallery-container -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in to CSS nth-child selectors. As an example you can check the following snippet.
[w3 Schools CSS3 Nth-Child Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row galRow">
        <div class="galRowImage">
            <img src="#" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="galRowText">some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row galRow">
        <div class="galRowImage">
            <img src="#" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="galRowText">some text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row galRow">
        <div class="galRowImage">
            <img src="#" alt=""/>
        </div>
        <div class="galRowText">some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .container{
        width: 400px;
    }
    .galRow:nth-child(even) .galRowImage, .galRow:nth-child(odd) .galRowImage{
        float: left;
    }   
    .galRow:nth-child(even) .galRowImage, .galRow:nth-child(odd) .galRowImage{
        float: right;
    }
</style>
```